# Firebaseの設定ファイルをGithubのPublicリポジトリに置いても問題ないでしょうか？

Tags: github, firebase

ポートフォリオのホスティングとしてFirebaseを使用しており、
ソースコードすべてをgit管理しています。(現状はprivateリポジトリ)

npmの`firebase-tools`を用いてデプロイしていますが、
package.jsonなどと同階層に生成された下記★マークのファイル(ディレクトリ)は
Githubの公開リポジトリにpushしても問題ないでしょうか？
（ファイルの中身はあまり大事な情報にも見えませんでしたが、不安なので質問させていただいてます。）

```
/project/
└─ node_modules/
└─ package.json
└─ .firebase/*.cache　★
└─ .firebaserc　★
└─ firebase.json　★
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

github上でfirebaseを使ったリポジトリを見てみるとわかるかと思います。
僕自信詳しくはないですが、`.firebaserc`と`.firebase/`は`.gitignore`に入れてgithub上にはあげてない人が多いようです。
上げないほうが安全でしょうね。

https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/blob/master/.gitignore